# What is wrong with my Cinnamon desktop

Tags: freeze

I am working and randomly the computer Freezes Mouse doesn't work, the keyboard doesn't work. So I must shut down the computer. It only does it with Fedora 39 Cinnamon desktop.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details on what your system is. Make? Model? Age?

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > General, there is an option to set the Cinnamon memory limit. It should be about 500MB, if you have more than 4GB memory. If Cinnamon exceeds this, it will restart the process. You will not lose your windows and progress in apps.

Comment: It may be a frozen desktop because of too much memory usage 